# Spring Boot actuator "public.databasechangelog" does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

In my Spring Boot project I have configure Actuator endpoints. I want to use `/liquibase` endpoint in order to check the Liquibase migration status but receiving a following exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "public.databasechangelog" does not exist
```

This is because I have reconfigured my project to use `system` PostgreSQL schema for technical Liquibase table instead of `public`.

How to tell actuator to look into `system` schema instead of `public` ?

**UPDATED**

I have configure Liquibase in a following way:

```
@Configuration
public class LiquibaseConfig {

    @Value("${liquibase.context}")
    private String context;

    @Value("${system.schemaName}")
    private String schemaName;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn(value = "loggerProperties")
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibaseExt(schemaName);

        liquibase.setContexts(context);
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:changelog/db.changelog.xml");

        return liquibase;
    }

    private static class SpringLiquibaseExt extends SpringLiquibase {

        private String schemaName;

        public SpringLiquibaseExt(String schemaName) {
            this.schemaName = schemaName;
        }

        @Override
        protected Database createDatabase(Connection c, ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor) throws DatabaseException {
            Database database = super.createDatabase(c, resourceAccessor);
            database.setLiquibaseSchemaName(schemaName); //schema = system

            return database;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: and how did you configure schema for liquibase, have you set up spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=system?

Comment: The actuator just asks liquibase so there's nothing to configure there...

Comment: @freakman I have updated my question with liquibase config. default_schema doesn't work because I want to separate my business tables from technical like databasechangelog